# 2 ACM Certificates in AWS, same DNS validation record. One stuck in Pending Validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I hope you are well,

I currently have 2 identical ACM certificates, one in us-east-1 and one in eu-central-1.

In route53, I have added the DNS CNAME record for validation.

The strange issue here is that despite sharing the same DNS record, the eu-central-1 certificate does not renew and stays in pending validation state, meanwhile the us-east-1 gets validated and renewed.

I have tried to create more certificates in eu-central-1 that as well I'm unable to validate.